# T where T:struct failing to support decimal variable

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have the generic function

```
private void WriteNumberProperties<T>(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<string, T?> fields) 
where T:struct {
        foreach(var kvp in fields) {
            writer.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key);
            if(kvp.Value.HasValue) {
                writer.WriteNumberValue(kvp.Value.Value);
            }else{
                writer.WriteNullValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

And i am trying to call it via:

```
WriteNumberProperties(writer, value.DecimalFields);
```

where T is `decimal`. Here is the exception i am getting:

```
Transformers\EntityDTOConverter.cs(70,45): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'decimal'
```

from my understanding, decimal is a struct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netcore-3.1

why is this saying T cannot be convert from T to decimal?

Comment: `T` can be any struct and may be not convertivle to decimal. Adding `Convert.ToDecimal` may work `writer.WriteNumberValue(Convert.ToDecimal(kvp.Value.Value));`

Comment: haha, literally after i submitted this, i realized this error. thanks for the quick response!

Comment: You can also add `IConvertible` to generic constraints to be sure, like `where T : struct, IConvertible` However, some types, like `DateTime`, doesn't support converting to decimal and you'll get a `InvalidCastException.` `Utf8JsonWriter ` has a separate methods for different types, better to use them, IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After staring at this, I realized I cannot use generics in this way for the numeric types because of how the utf8jsonwriter does not have an overload for stuct. the class only has writers for the concrete value types (decimal, long, int, etc).

I really wish generics had an OR operator for generic definitions, but it is not supported.